# how to create and use databases (and tables) with simple Coldfusion applications while using Xampp (Guidance for Newbies)

Tags: coldfusion, xampp, coldfusionbuilder

I want to do simple CRUD operations for simple ColdFusion applications. I have simple guidelines but not deep guidance for that and it looks a little tricky for me. Anyone there who can provide a simple and detailed solution for that. Actually I have created database and tables on `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` but how can I use the database and tables in CF-Builder applications, I don't know that. If I'm missing anything else, please mention it.
Thanks,

Comment: For simple ColdFusion applications, the databases and tables will have have been created in advance and the appropriate permissions will have been granted.  The software you use to do that depends on the database engine you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Before someone closes this, check out this intro to CFBuilder that shows you how to connect to a database:

http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-adobe

Then go through the lessons at http://www.learncfinaweek.com/. If you've done CRUD apps in any other language, you just have to learn the CF syntax for doing the same processes.

Answer (score 1):

In CFBuilder 2 and 3, there is a view, "RDS Dataview" that shows the hosts (ColdFusion servers) you've provided connection information for.

Expanding a servername shows the datasources defined in its ColdFusion Administrator. You can drill down from Server to Datasource (schema) to the tables, to the fields. You can right-click a tableName and choose RDS Query Viewer and get a query builder, much like Microsoft Accesses, if you're familiar with that.

Alternatively you can just drag and drop tablenames and fieldnames directly into your hand-crafted code to save a lot of typing.

See Adobe Docs at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec16ab8-7ff9.html
There is also a CRUD creator described on that page, that can introspect a table and produce a CRUD cfc... not cruddy!